# Finding the last 14 days of messages in Conversations.History

Tags: slack-api

I am trying to use the Slack API and specifically the conversations.history url. I am trying to pull just the last 14 days of messages, but I can not seem to figure out how to do so with the "Oldest" Parameter and passing the last 14 days through that. I want this to be automated so that everyday it shows just the last 14 days, rather then putting a Unix ts in of 14 days ago. Is this possible?

I Have tried to manipulate the ts, but nothing seems to work other then a number as the input. This will not work for me as I always want to pull in the latest 14 days.

Answer (score 1):

The `oldest` property requires an absolute timestamp. You can not user relative times like last 14 days etc. So your app needs to calculate the correct timestamp when it calls the API.

Also take note of the correct format. It includes fractions of a second, e.g. `1512085950.000216`.

Here the [docu](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history) for reference.